# Display all drives, files, and subfolders in treeview

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for the simplest way to display all drives, files, and subfolders in a treeview.  If someone's got a snippet of code to do this that they don't mind sharing I would really appreciate it.

The closest I've gotten was this code I tried using, but it gave me a "IOException was unhandled" error saying "The device is not ready." error at runtime (after about 5-10 sec) on the line below

```
Dim folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
```

underneath is the rest of the code

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim drives As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of IO.DriveInfo) = My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
    Dim rootDir As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 0 To drives.Count - 1
        rootDir = drives(i).Name
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootDir)
        PopulateTreeView(rootDir, TreeView1.Nodes(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTreeView(ByVal dir As String, ByVal parentNode As TreeNode)
    Dim folder As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Dim folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
        If folders.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim childNode As TreeNode = Nothing
            For Each folder In folders
                childNode = New TreeNode(folder)
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode)
                PopulateTreeView(folder, childNode)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(folder & ": Access Denied")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and where it is failing? It's better to provide something to start with. People will not just write your code.

Comment: Sure a recursive function would work, but it will be slow if the root is picked.

Comment: You should also use the EnumerateDirectories instead of GetDirectories because you can begin to enumerate the results before all the data is returned.  With GetDirectories, you have to wait until the call is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're off to a good start. The `IOException` you receive is most likely caused by your procedure trying to list contents on an empty disc drive, which is obviously impossible.

The fix is simple:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To drives.Count - 1
    If Not drives(i).IsReady Then
        Continue For
    End If
    rootDir = drives(i).Name
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootDir)
    PopulateTreeView(rootDir, TreeView1.Nodes(i))
Next
```

Besides that, I recommend not loading folder contents until a node is clicked. Limit the recursive call to 1 level (current directory + content of all its subdirectories). That way, you get the best performance while still being able to determine whether a subdirectory should have the treeview expand button.