# Displaying SPECIFIC folders/files in treeview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

After scouring the internet for a way to do this that was a lite as possible, I was not able to find something that was working for me. I have taken the coding from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090860/display-all-drives-files-and-subfolders-in-treeview) in an attempt to make it work but cannot figure out how to save my life. Here is what I have:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Get a list of drives
    Dim drives As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of DriveInfo) = My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives
    Dim rootDir As String = String.empty
    'Now loop thru each drive and populate the treeview
    For i As Integer = 0 To drives.Count - 1
        rootDir = drives(i).Name
        'Add this drive as a root node
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootDir)
        'Populate this root node
        PopulateTreeView(rootDir, TreeView1.Nodes(i))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTreeView(ByVal dir As String, ByVal parentNode As TreeNode)
    Dim folder As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Dim folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
        If folders.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim childNode As TreeNode = Nothing
            For Each folder In folders
                childNode = New TreeNode(folder)
                parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode)
                PopulateTreeView(folder, childNode)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(folder & ": Access Denied")
    End Try
End Sub
```

However it only lists the drives & their folders and I need it to list the directories and files from a specific directory right from the beginning without having to go all the way down the tree to find what you are specifically looking for. I have tried changing `rootDir` to the address of the specific folder that I am trying to access, but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to only display folders/files on expanded parents? Your current implementation will list every file in every folder on the entire machine. It takes forever. Why don't you just start with top level directories and `PopulateTreeView` when the user clicks to expand one? Much faster and less intensive all at once.

Comment: What I am trying to do is take the code above, and it function for a specific path rather than all the drives.

Comment: The code above already will work on a specific path. Call PopulateTreeView like this: `PopulateTreeView(yourPath, TreeView1.Nodes(0))`. Have a look at my answer below, you'll notice that it does do it for a specific path and is triggered on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but based on my comment in the original question: this code will do what I said in that comment. It's written in C# [but here is a converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). Also: it's probably not production ready, but it's a start.

```
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get a list of drives
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        string rootDir = string.Empty;
        //Now loop thru each drive and populate the treeview
        for (int i = 0; i <= drives.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            rootDir = drives[i].Name;
            //Add this drive as a root node
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootDir);
            //Populate this root node
            PopulateTreeView(rootDir, TreeView1.Nodes[i]);
        }

    }
    private void PopulateTreeView(string dir, TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        string folder = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
            if (folders.Length != 0)
            {
                TreeNode childNode = null;
                foreach (string folder_loopVariable in folders)
                {
                    folder = folder_loopVariable;
                    childNode = new TreeNode(folder);
                    childNode.Nodes.Add("");
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                }
            }
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            if (files.Length != 0)
            {
                TreeNode childNode = null;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    childNode = new TreeNode(file);
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(folder + ": Access Denied");
        }
    }

    private void TreeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode actual = e.Node;
        actual.Nodes[0].Remove();
        PopulateTreeView(actual.Text, actual);
    }

    private void TreeView1_BeforeCollapse(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode actual = e.Node;
        actual.Nodes.Clear();
        actual.Nodes.Add("");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! That works for what I need it to after I converted it, no issues at all. The one thing I am having issues with however,and this is probably something really easy to fix, I'm just too dumb to figure it out, it why it will only list down one folder. Example: It lists the drives, I expand one of the drives, it lists the folders/files, I expand the folder, nothing is listed. Any pointers?

Comment: So this was weird. I have all of the stuff I've helped people with on S.O. in one project so I can go back and reference it at a later date (for this exact reason). I uncommented your problem (which was working originally) and all of a sudden I ran into the problem you described... I assume you copy and pasted my code? Since you're in C#, the form editor wont automatically wire up the event handling code to form controls. Click your treeview in the designer, select the lightning bolt in the properties tab and change "BeforeCollapse" and "BeforeExpand" to the void methods copied from above.

Comment: Oh and also: If my answer was the accepted answer, remember to accept it as the answer to your question ;)

Comment: Two more things: It is listing the second level directories twice now, back to back. I open the top folder and everything is listed twice. Also, I don't want to open a new question just for this. Is it possible to remove everything from the filename except for the actual filename itself. Example: C:\folder\index.html becomes just index.html?

Comment: Second level directories listed twice: Check your Treeview's events. Be sure that "BeforeCollapse" is set to "Treeview1_BeforeCollapse" and "BeforeExpand" is set to "Treeview1_BeforeExpand". I was able to reproduce the double directories by having both events set to "TreeView1_BeforeExpand". I'd post a picture to make it easier but corporate policy prohibits imgur.com

Comment: Removing from the file path: Yes it's possible, but it will require more work. Since the treeview expand relies on that full string name to know where it is, you'd have to create your own object (or use a dictionary or keyvaluepair maybe?) to expose the human readable (stripped) string and the full path at the same time. Unless you want it only on file names and not folders, at which point it's fairly easy